# Partition function in Matlab - is there something missing in my code?

Tags: function, matlab

Can anyone see if there is something wrong in my matlab code? My objective is to replicate this formula:[image]

q can take value 1,2,3 and 5. 
I constructed my vector Xt where each element are a cumulative sum of log(1+return) at each time (t) - for stock returns - first element is normalized to log(1).

Then to compute each element Sq(T,delta t) for the four values of q this is my matlab code:

```
for j=1:length(dt);
E=Xt(1:dt(j):end);
EE=diff(E(2:end));
EEE=diff(E(1:end-1));
Sqone(j)=sum(abs(EE-EEE).^1);
Sqtwo(j)=sum(abs(EE-EEE).^2);
Sqthree(j)=sum(abs(EE-EEE).^3);
Sqfive(j)=sum(abs(EE-EEE).^5); end;
```

Is there something wrong in the code above? I am asking this because I know there is something wrong since I am not getting the expected results. I am convinced that it is due to my code posted above.

the vector dt is a vector that goes from 1 to high number - depending on the size of Xt. But my vector dt is not the problem.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: is T a constant? Can you give an example of the expected result and the wrong result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the difference twice. Once using `diff` and once using `EE-EEE`. The correct code is:

```
for j=1:length(dt);
E=Xt(1:dt(j):end);
EE=abs(diff(E));
Sqone(j)=sum(EE.^1);
Sqtwo(j)=sum(EE.^2);
Sqthree(j)=sum(EE.^3);
Sqfive(j)=sum(EE.^5); end;
```